# How to remove everything between a slash sign and first space after in r

Tags: r, gsub

How to remove everything between a slash sign and first space after in r?

```
#Input:
#"David\adfghsrth333 McDonalds", "Alice Jennifer\dfgadfg555 Smith", 

#Desired output:
#"David McDonalds", "Alice Jennifer Smith"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have your input in a character vector called `strings`, you can remove the characters between the slash sign and the following space like this

```
gsub('\\\\\\w+', '', strings)
```

The regular expression used looks strange because the backslash is a special character in both R and in regex.

- `"\\\\"` matches `\`; note that we need so many slashes because we need to escape the special character in both R and regex
- `\\w+` only matches word characters (numbers, letters, and underscores) so it stops matching when a space is reached

Comment: It returns the original string without change: strings <- c("David\adfghsrth333 McDonalds",  "Alice Jennifer\fgadfg555 Smith")
> strings <- gsub("\\\\\\w+", "" , strings)
> strings
[1] "David\adfghsrth333 McDonalds"   "Alice Jennifer\fgadfg555 Smith"

Comment: @williamyarmar It looks like in the example you are using, the slash is not actually a slash but an escape character telling R to treat \a and \f different characters entirely. R stores the `\` itself as `\\`, so a vector with backslashes would look like this `c("David\\adfghsrth333 McDonalds", "Alice Jennifer\\fgadfg555 Smith")`. In actual use, will you be dealing with real backslashes or with various special characters?

Comment: Mostly backslashes or slashes (/ \).